# unable to use textfield's addTarget method inside collectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uitextfield

**Issue:**

I'm unable to use `moveTaskTextfieldBottomAnchor` objective C method that I created. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
class ConstructQuestHeader: UICollectionViewCell {
 lazy var taskTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "What task needs to be done?"
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveTaskTextfieldBottomAnchor), for: .touchDown)
    return tf
 }()

 @objc func moveTaskTextfieldBottomAnchor() {
    print("moving taskTextfield")
 }
}
```

Comment: `UITextField` doesn't have `.touchDown` event. You got to use delegate method instead.

Comment: You could use `.editingDidBegin` instead of `.touchDown`